# Как сделать реализацию модели возобновления исключения?

Tags: java, исключения

Я не могу понять, как сделать реализацию модели возобновления, используя цикл ***while***, который выполняется до тех пор, пока исключение не перестанет выдаваться

Comment: Исключение отлавливается в блоке try{} далее выбирается подходящий catch(){} и управление передается именно туда. Когда исключение обработано , то есть закончилось выполнение блока catch(){} , выполняется блок finally{} , если он имеется конечно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цикл while, который выполняется до тех пор, пока исключение не перестанет выдаваться:

```
while(true) {
  try {
    //код, выбрасывающий исключение
    break;
  }catch(IOException e) {
    //Тут обрабатываем исключение, если надо.
  }
}
```

То есть если было выброшено исключение, то оно будет обработано в блоке catch(), а затем продолжится цикл. А если исключение не было выброшено, то цикл прервется на строке `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример рекурсивного вызова метода в результате выкинутого исключения.Пример в связи с использованием рекурсии не очень корректный но принцип реализации я думаю ясен:

```
public boolean example(int x) {
    boolean result = true;
    int step = x;
    try {
        for (int i = x; i < 10; ++i) {
            step = i;
            if (i < 6) {
                throw new Exception();
            } else {
                System.out.println(result);
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        result = this.example(++step);
    }
    return result;
}
```

вот еще один пример.В данном случае логика опирается на изменение флага:

```
public void example() {
    boolean flag = true;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            try {
                if (i < 6) {
                    throw new Exception();
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    } while (flag);
}
```